# Laplace in the disc

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm given,

$$\begin{align}\Delta u &:= u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r}u_r + \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta} =0, \qquad \text{for } r<a, \; -\pi < \theta < \pi \tag{1} \\
u\mid_{r=a} & = f(\theta) \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

the question is "what condition should $f(\theta)$ satisfy?"

For my attempt, so far I used separation of variables $u(r,\theta) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ to get $$ 
\underbrace{\frac{r^2R''+rR'}{R}}_{\displaystyle\lambda} + \underbrace{\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}}_{\displaystyle-\lambda} = 0
$$ Which gives me $$\begin{align}
r^2R'' + rR' - \lambda R & = 0 \tag{3} \\
\Theta'' + \lambda\Theta & = 0 \tag{4} \\
\Theta(-\pi) = \Theta(\pi) & = 0 \tag{5} \\
u(a, \theta) = R(a)\Theta(\theta) & = f(\theta) \tag{6} 
\end{align}
$$ I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track. Equations (4) and (5) look like an eigenvalue problem, but the boundary condition (5) gives me a zero eigenvalue.

Comment: What condition should $f$ satisfy in order to what?

Comment: Is not that a given initial condition?@Trvor Mason

Comment: @Narasimham I'm an idiot. That's exactly what its asking. I was thinking it was some special property an f(theta) must have...